# Does the European Union play any role in mediating conflicts related to industrial espionage between two member countries?

Tags: european-union, espionage

> AFP - France is the top offender when it comes to industrial
> espionage, and is even worse than China and Russia, the head of a
> German company was quoted as saying in a leaked US diplomatic cable
> made public Tuesday.
>
> "France is the evil empire (in) stealing technology, and Germany knows
> this," Berry Smutny, the head of German satellite company OHB
> Technology, was quoted as saying in the diplomatic note obtained by
> WikiLeaks and released by the Norwegian daily Aftenposten.
>
> Germany, with its decentralised government, was however not willing to
> do much to counter French industrial espionage activities, he was
> paraphrased as saying.
>
> "Going on at length of his (disdain) of the French, Smutny said French
> IPR (intellectual property rights) espionage is so bad that the total
> damage done to the German economy is greater than that inflicted by
> China or Russia," read the cable, dated November 20, 2009.

https://www.france24.com/en/20110104-france-industrial-espionage-economy-germany-russia-china-business

Does the European Union play any role in mediating conflicts related to industrial espionage between two member countries? You would think that because France and Germany are two economically powerful countries within the European Union and the European Union deals in everything from diplomacy to economic policies, the European Union would play a sort of mediating role between the two, but is this the case, or is there another organization specifically made to settle such disputes?

Comment: I think this is mostly the personal opinion of Mr Smutny. From some quick googling OHB employs around 3000 people so it is not that big and works in satelite and aerospace technology, an area where Germany and France don't really compete but are rather both part of the EU efforts in the area.

Comment: A German company that believes its intellectual property to have been stolen by a French company would sue the French company in a German or French court.  There wouldn't normally be a dispute between Germany and France for the EU to get involved in.